# I'm trying to make a random name generator, but the output is off every time

Tags: python, random

The generator is supposed make 10 names and pull the names from the tuples first and last then randomly generate an index and assign it to either first or last then append/write each first + last name to the .txt file as well as put each name on a new line. It's supposed to also removed the names from the copied list to ensure there are no name duplicates.

```
def generateNames(firstName, lastName, file):
   
   
    for i in range (10):
        firstName = list(firstName)
        lastName = list(lastName)
        name = (random.choice(firstName) + " " + random.choice(lastName))
        print(name)        
    print("\t\tYour Generated Names:")
```

Whenever the code generates the names it looks like this

```
Please enter a file name:
d

Hit Enter to Generate.

. x
x t
. t
t .
d .
d t
t t
x x
x x
t x
        Your Generated Names:


File has been created.
```

Rather than the full names.

Comment: Please try to add code that could be executed by persons without knowing what is inside your files. This will make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def generateNames(firstName, lastName, file):
```

It seems like you're expecting `firstName` and `lastName` to be lists of names, but they're not.  They're just strings.

Calling `random.choice()` on those values returns an *individual letter*.

Look at the code that calls this function, and make sure you're passing the proper arguments.

Comment: So I should move the firstName = list(firstName) lastName = list(lastName) before the generator?

Comment: @Mentos No.  `firstName` and `lastName ` should _already_ be lists when they are passed in to this function.  Then you don't need to call `list()` at all.

Comment: @Mentos For more help, you'll have to show us the calling code and how it creates the arguments that are passed to this function.

Answer (score 0):

According to your report (result that you show) you are running this function with two strings as arguments. If you run it with list of strings it's a bit better.

```
In [8]: generateNames(["AAA", "BBBB"], ["YY", "ZZZ"], "")
BBBB YY
BBBB YY
AAA YY
BBBB YY
AAA YY
AAA YY
BBBB YY
AAA ZZZ
AAA YY
AAA ZZZ
```

Also, to use one name only once you could make this edit:

```
def generate_names(first_names, last_names):
    random.shuffle(first_names)
    random.shuffle(last_names)
    for i in range (10):
        first_name = first_names.pop()
        last_name = last_names.pop()
        name = f"{first_names} {last_names}"
        print(name)
```

This function expects two lists of names.
It shuffles them at the beginning.
Then it uses .pop method which returns one value and removes it from the list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It sure does, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the firstName and lastName in square brackets outside the for loop. Best of Luck!

```
firstName = [firstName]
lastName = [lastName]

for i in range (10):
    name = (random.choice(firstName) + " " + random.choice(lastName))
    print(name)        
print("\t\tYour Generated Names:")
```